# Mysql opposite 2 where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table what contains data

```
Id    local_id    user_id
=========================
1    1            null
2    1            1
3    2            null
4    2            1
5    5            null
```

I need query what return row from local_id=1 and all rows where user_id=null
example id what return: 1,2,3,5

Comment: correct spelling is "opposite"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do then is use a `WHERE` condition to filter by either `local_id` or `user_id`

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM table
WHERE local_id = 1 OR user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: DISTINCT is optional?

Comment: you can remove it and see if you dont get duplicate ids